# Activate radiobutton when text box is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to setup some Javascript form validation on a form that I am working on.  I have all of the validation working, but one thing I have been tasked with doing I can't seem to figure out and can't find many articles online about it.

The challenge that I have is that if a user wants to type in the "Other" field on a text box I want the "Other" radio button to automatically get checked.  Here's the code I had in there that obviously isn't working for me.

```
if (f.OtherTextValue.value !== '')
{
    document.getElementById("OtherTextRadio").checked = true;
    return false;
}
```

So what I think I am trying to do is this: If the OtherTextValue (my text box) is not blank then go get the ID of my Radio button and make it checked/selected.

I am still fairly new in the world of Javascript, but am trying to learn.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind an event handler to the `text` element, and then set the state of the `checkbox` according to whether there is a value or not:

```
$('#OtherTextValue').on('keyup', function() {
  $('#OtherTextRadio').prop('checked', !!this.value.length);
});
```

You may want to use additional events, as this only triggers when a key is released. [Check the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

#### [Here's a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/7qN29/1/)

Answer (score 0):

To check use `prop`:

```
$('#OtherTextRadio').prop('checked', true);
```

I dont see your code so maybe in final shoud look like this:

```
if($('#OtherTextValue').val() == "Other") {
    $('#OtherTextRadio').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 if ($('#OtherTextValue').val('Other'))) {
    $('#OtherTextRadio').prop('checked', true);   
  }
});
```

> Usually on clicking the "Other" radio button, enable the textBox., but yours idea seems to be different. Please do more research.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without JQuery, as your code in the question suggests, I have mocked up something in JSFiddle that might help:
http://jsfiddle.net/xAcbm/

The key here is to link your check to an event, in this example I've added a simple button:

```
<input type="radio" id="chlVal" name="selVal" value="Val 1"/>Value 1<br/>
<input type="radio" id="chkOther" name="selVal" value="Other"/>Other<br/>
<input type="text" id="txtOther">
<button id="btn" onclick="Javascript: checkOther()">Check Form</button>
```

The Javascript is:

```
function checkOther()
{
    if (document.getElementById('txtOther').value!='')
    {
        alert('Value in the box');
        document.getElementById('chkOther').checked=1;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

use onchange event

```
<asp:radiobutton ID="OtherTextRadio" runat="server"></asp:radiobutton>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onchange="checkRadio();" ></asp:TextBox>
```

script is given below

```
   function checkRadio() {

       if (document.getElementById("TextBox1").value != "") {
           document.getElementById("OtherTextRadio").checked = true;
       }
       else document.getElementById("OtherTextRadio").checked = false;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sourcetext').on('click', function() {
        $('#sourcecheck').prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```