# Activating radiobutton upon typing in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Question is basically a follow-up on [Activate radiobutton when text box is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404744/activate-radiobutton-when-text-box-is-selected) which is quite old.

I've taken the code from the accepted answer and adapted it to my page. It works in jfiddle (I copied the bits from my page in jfiddle for testing), it doesn't work in my page. From some more digging I figured I have to add something called jQuery, which I did. It still doesn't work.

Importing jquery in the head section of my html:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Relevant code snippet from my page:

```
<script>
$('#sourcetext').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#sourcecheck').prop('checked', !!this.value.length);
});
</script>
<p><input type="radio" name="source" id="sourcecheck" value="meetup"  /> Meetup, group: <input type="text" name="meetupgroup" id="sourcetext" value="" /></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="source" value="facebook" checked /> Facebook</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="source" value="timeout"  /> Time Out Magazine</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="source" value="hkmagazine"  /> HK Magazine</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="source" value="other"  /> Other: <input type="text" name="sourceother" value="" /> </p>
```

Now the question: what am I possibly doing wrong here?

Comment: `!!this.value.length` ==> `this.value.length` right.?

Answer (score 0):

Place the `<script>` tags containing your code at the bottom of the markup - or wrap your code in a DOM ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: This may be a correct answer if only I could really understand what you're trying to say!